# Storyboard add viewcontroller's view into another viewcontroller iOS5+

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Anyone know if it is possible to create your views in the storyboard which can be used for a main view?

I have tried instantiating my viewcontroller with the identifier and then adding the view from the viewcontroller, but the frame isn't the same as the frame I used in the storyboard.

I know it is possible to use the container view in the storyboard. But I cant use that in iOS 5.0.

Comment: Sorry i dont really understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish. What is expected and what do you get as a result ?

Comment: Very much like a UITabBarController, but instead of switching a viewcontroller, which the views out instead. But I would like to see these views in the Storyboard too.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create viewcontroller in storyboard. Create a separate xib file then instantiate controller using xib and add the view as subview in main view.